# TabItem Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, tabitem

I have a TabControl that has this TabItem in XAML.

```
<controls:TabItem x:Name="UserNameOn1" Background="LightGray" Height="25"  Visibility="Visible"  IsSelected="False" MouseLeftButtonDown="teste110_MouseLeftButtonDown">
      <controls:TabItem.Header>
           <StackPanel x:Name="TabitemPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                   <Image x:Name="UserImage" Source="/Tese;component/Images/user_act.png" Width="30" Height="15" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" ImageFailed="UserImage_ImageFailed"/>
                   <TextBlock Name="Userdisplay"  Text="UserName" Margin="30,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
           </StackPanel>
      </controls:TabItem.Header>
```

and in C# I Want to change the Userdisplay Text to conta.Username_v as below, the problem is that by doing this my image inside the TabItem disappears how to make change only the TextBlock and maintain the image

```
UserNameOn1.Header = conta.Username_v;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
at event or form load whenever you want.

Userdisplay.text = conta.Username_v;
```

this will chage only the textbox's text only and not effect other

Comment: Thanks that's what I needed,don't know why I didn't try that before